# Lookup most used text in range based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

I have the following CSE formula to return the most used text in a range,excluding empty cells.

```
=INDEX(A4:D4,MODE(IF(A4:D4<>"",MATCH(A4:D4,A4:D4,0))))
```

My problem is that the formula returns #NA when there is only one value in the range. How can I adjust the formula to return that value?

Comment: You'd also get #N/A if the range contained a b c d (because there is no most used text and therefore no mode) so you'd need to make a decision on which one to choose.

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for the reply. The data will never vary for every cell in the range, but in some cases there will only be a single value. I cannot use the IFERROR function, as there may be other errors (which is fine) other than a single value which I want to use..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only concerned with a single cell being present causing problems and wanting to retrieve use this CSE:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A4:D4,"*"),  INDEX(A4:D4,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A4:D4),0)),INDEX(A4:D4,MODE(IF(A4:D4<>"",MATCH(A4:D4,A4:D4,0)))))
```

Otherise, with all distinct values being present or no mode in general,

You can count the distinct values and use that tested against the number of columns. If equal there is no mode and so use If statement to default into handling the True.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A4:D4,A4:D4))=COLUMNS(A4:D4),"Do Something",INDEX(A4:D4,MODE(IF(A4:D4<>"",MATCH(A4:D4,A4:D4,0)))))
```

Again, a CSE so enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This bit of above formula counts the unique values:

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A4:D4,A4:D4))
```